# How to extract all nested <option> tags and their content with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull out all nested `<option>` tags and their values using `BeautifulSoup` in Python.
The first block of code provides the desired Unicode-type result (more than 60 pages of output). Part of the HTML tree is included below. Please note that the desired `<option>` tags are nested.

Issue: The second block of code below does not provide the output, throwing no error.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def main(base_url):
    response = requests.get(base_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    print(soup.prettify)
        
main('https://meps.ahrq.gov/data_stats/download_data_files.jsp')
```

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def main(base_url):
    response = requests.get(base_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    select_id = soup.find_all("select", id="pufnumber")
    print(select_id)
    nested_option = [x.find_all("option") for x in select_id] 
    print(nested_option)
    
main('https://meps.ahrq.gov/data_stats/download_data_files.jsp')
```

Part of the output from `print(soup.prettify)`:

```html
</table>
<!-- 3/23/06 <img src="../images/bullets/spacer.gif" width="1" height="3" alt="">
            <table role="presentation" width="430" height="15" border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td height="0" bgcolor="#F9F9F9" class="contentStyle"><strong><font color="#006600">Option
                2: </font><font color="#003399"><label for="pufnumber">Select by data file number/title </label></font></strong></td>
        </tr>
      </table>      
      <table role="presentation" width="430" height="25" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="BlueBox">
        <tr>
          <td width="430" height="0"> <span class="contentStyle">
     
            <select id="pufnumber" size=1 name="cboPufNumber">
            <option value="All">All data files</option>
        
                    
              <option value="HC-225">MEPS HC-225: MEPS Panel 24 Longitudinal Data File</option> 
                    
                    
              <option value="HC-224">MEPS HC-224: 2020 Full Year Consolidated Data File</option> 
                    
                    
              <option value="HC-223">MEPS HC-223: 2020 Person Round Plan File</option>
```

My goal is to pull out nested option tags like this:

```html
<option value="HC-225">MEPS HC-225: MEPS Panel 24 Longitudinal Data File</option>
```

I'm not interested in the following `<option>` tags:

```html
<option value="All">All available years</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the part of the HTML you want to process is in a comment block, which means the BeautifulSoup cannot process the content.

```
<!-- 3/23/06 <img src=" -->
```

Try the code below to see all the comments,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

def main(base_url):
   response = requests.get(base_url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
   comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
   for c in comments:
       print(c)
       print("===========")
   c.extract()
main('https://meps.ahrq.gov/data_stats/download_data_files.jsp')
```

Now, your problem becomes how to process the comments to extract the data you want.

Here is a working example, and I used the regular expression to process the raw text. Note that this is only designed for the specific web page structure and might not be useful for other sites.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import re

# find all options match the start and end string
def extractOptions(inputData):
    sub1 = str(re.escape('<option value="All">All data files</option>'))
    sub2 = str(re.escape('</select>'))
    result = re.findall(sub1+"(.*)"+sub2, inputData, flags=re.S)
    if len(result) > 0:
        return result[0]

# find the actual data from each option
def extracData(inputData):
    sub1 = str(re.escape('>'))
    sub2 = str(re.escape('</option>'))
    result =  re.findall(sub1+"(.*)"+sub2, inputData, flags=re.S)
    if len(result) > 0:
        return result[0]
    return ''

def main(base_url):
   response = requests.get(base_url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
   comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

   for c in comments:
       if '<select id="pufnumber" size=1 name="cboPufNumber">' in c:
        options = extractOptions(c)
        ops = options.splitlines() #split text into lines
        for op in ops:
            data = extracData(op)
            if data != '': #check if the data found
                print(data)
       
   
main('https://meps.ahrq.gov/data_stats/download_data_files.jsp')
```

Comment: I'm a Python novice. I wonder whether it is necessary to remove the comments from the parsed tree and create a comments-free soup object before pulling out the  nested option tags. How would I proceed? Any further guidance  would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @user1849365 Well, it requires a bit more work to process text. I have updated the answer and hope it helps.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your help with these fantastic Python scripts that provide me with the desired output. Thank you, again!

Comment: Pleasure. I will much appreciate if you can accept this answer.

Comment: I clicked "The answer is useful" and accepted this answer (i.e., the latest edited code snippets). Thanks.

Comment: You helped me write two functions in Python. As a result, I have drafted a short paper,  Web Scraping to Create a List of All MEPS-HC Data File Download URLs: SAS and Python Solutions, for possible submission to a SAS Users’ Group meeting.

Would you be interested in co-authoring with me on that paper for authorship credit? In that case, you need to go over the Python component of the manuscript and contribute to it. However, I am required to get approval from my office before adding you as a co-author. Thanks,

Comment: @user1849365 thanks so much for the opportunity being a co-author. Yes, I am happy to go over the Python code. Here is my email address https://zero.inde.nz/?c8c52bc88d4d5890#HcV8bBARihapW7dxtaiM7W6931DFeiuJKwQa5eATQBmq